# Catch url without parameters

Tags: regex

I'm having issues catching url while excluding parameters (what's after `?` sign)

So for the following links

```
/alfa/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
/beta/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?parameter=value
```

I need the following

```
alfa /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
beta /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
```

So far I came up with the following but it always catch full link including parameters, which I don't need

```
^(/alfa|beta)?(/wp-(content|admin|includes).*)
```

Comment: Why not use a URI parser? This is not always easy.

Comment: So [this](https://regex101.com/r/vHRH3A/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your inputs always ended in .js)

```
(/(alfa|beta)(/wp-(content|admin|includes).*))(\.js|\?)
```

Or improving upon ctwheels' comment:

```
^/(alfa|beta)([^?\s]*)(\.js|\?)
```

I'm not sure if it's 100% what you need but I ran that query in regexpal.com and it works as you described.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it never catch any links without parameters

Comment: @JoeS Try now. Sorry I forgot to include a conditional

Comment: still not working, using the latest update it will catch all

Comment: Wait. In my previous version. Can't you just assume in your code that the result has no parameters if it finds no matches? That's what I would do. @JoeS

Comment: sorry i'am using this along Nginx rewrite so i need an exact regex.

Comment: Try the second regex I added. @JoeS

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(\/(alfa|beta)[^\?]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/AmgHTS/8